# Fastest way to read a fastq with scikit-bio

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics, skbio

I am trying to read a fastq formatted text file using [scikit-bio](http://scikit-bio.org/).

Given that it is a fairly large file, performing operations is quite slow.

Ultimately, I am attempting to dereplicate the fastq file into a dictionary:

```
f = 'Undetermined_S0_L001_I1_001.fastq'
seqs = skbio.io.read(f, format='fastq')

seq_dic = {}
for seq in seqs:
    seq = str(seq)
    if seq in seq_dic.keys():
        seq_dic[seq] +=1
    else:
        seq_dic[seq] = 1
```

Most of the time here is used during the reading of the file:

```
%%time
f = 'Undetermined_S0_L001_I1_001.fastq'
seqs = skbio.io.read(f, format='fastq')

for seq in itertools.islice(seqs, 100000):
    seq

CPU times: user 46.2 s, sys: 334 ms, total: 46.5 s
Wall time: 47.8 s
```

My understanding is that not verifying the sequences would improve run time, however that does not appear to be the case:

```
%%time
f = 'Undetermined_S0_L001_I1_001.fastq'
seqs = skbio.io.read(f, format='fastq', verify=False, variant='illumina1.8')

for seq in itertools.islice(seqs, 100000):
    seq

CPU times: user 47 s, sys: 369 ms, total: 47.4 s
Wall time: 48.9 s
```

So my question is, first why isn't `verify=False` improving run time and second is there a faster way using scikit-bio to read sequences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> first why isn't verify=False improving run time

`verify=False` is a parameter accepted by scikit-bio's I/O API generally. It is not specific to a particular file format. `verify=False` tells scikit-bio to not invoke the file format's sniffer to double-check that the file is in the format specified by the user. From the docs [1]:

```
verify : bool, optional
    When True, will double check the format if provided.
```

So `verify=False` doesn't turn off *sequence data validation*; it turns off file format sniffer verification. You will have minimal performance gains with `verify=False`.

`seqs = skbio.io.read(f, format='fastq', verify=False, variant='illumina1.8')` will produce a generator of `skbio.Sequence` objects. Sequence alphabet validation is not performed because `skbio.Sequence` does not have an alphabet, so that isn't where your performance bottleneck is. Note that if you want to read your FASTQ file into a specific type of biological sequence (DNA, RNA, or Protein), you can pass `constructor=skbio.DNA` (for example). This *will* perform alphabet validation for the relevant sequence type, and that currently cannot be toggled off when reading. Since you're having performance issues, I don't recommend passing `constructor` as that will only slow things down even more.

> and second is there a faster way using scikit-bio to read sequences?

There isn't a faster way to read FASTQ files with scikit-bio. There is an issue [2] exploring ideas that could speed this up, but those ideas haven't been implemented.

scikit-bio is slow at reading FASTQ files because it supports reading sequence data and quality scores that may span multiple lines. This complicates the reading logic and has a performance hit. FASTQ files with multi-line data are not common anymore however; Illumina used to produce these files but they now prefer/recommend writing FASTQ records that are exactly four lines (sequence header, sequence data, quality header, quality scores). In fact, this is how scikit-bio writes FASTQ data. With this simpler record format, it is much faster and easier to read a FASTQ file. scikit-bio is also slow at reading FASTQ files because it decodes and validates the quality scores. It also stores sequence data and quality scores in a `skbio.Sequence` object, which has performance overhead.

In your case, you don't need the quality scores decoded, and you likely have a FASTQ file with simple four-line records. Here's a Python 3 compatible generator that reads a FASTQ file and yields sequence data as Python strings:

```
import itertools

def read_fastq_seqs(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as fh:
        for seq_header, seq, qual_header, qual in itertools.zip_longest(*[fh] * 4):
            if any(line is None for line in (seq_header, seq, qual_header, qual)):
                raise Exception(
                    "Number of lines in FASTQ file must be multiple of four "
                    "(i.e., each record must be exactly four lines long).")
            if not seq_header.startswith('@'):
                raise Exception("Invalid FASTQ sequence header: %r" % seq_header)
            if qual_header != '+\n':
                raise Exception("Invalid FASTQ quality header: %r" % qual_header)
            if qual == '\n':
                raise Exception("FASTQ record is missing quality scores.")

            yield seq.rstrip('\n')
```

You can remove the validation checks here if you're certain your file is a valid FASTQ file containing records that are exactly four lines long.

This isn't related to your question, but I wanted to note that you may have a bug in your counter logic. When you see a sequence for the first time, your counter is set to zero instead of 1. I think the logic should be:

```
if seq in seq_dic:  # calling .keys() is necessary
    seq_dic[seq] +=1
else:
    seq_dic[seq] = 1
```

[1] http://scikit-bio.org/docs/latest/generated/skbio.io.registry.read.html

[2] https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/issues/907

Comment: Thanks @jairideout this is a great response/solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of occurrences of each unique sequence in a fastq file, I would suggest to try out the [Bank](https://github.com/GATB/pyGATB/wiki/Bank-API) parser of [pyGATB](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyGATB/0.1.2), together with the convenient `Counter` object from the `collections` module of the standard library.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from collections import Counter
from gatb import Bank

# (gunzipping is done transparently)
seq_counter = Counter(seq.sequence for seq in Bank("SRR077487_2.filt.fastq.gz"))
```

This is quite efficient for a python module (according to my benchmarks in Bioinformatics SE: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/380/292).

This counter should behave like your `seq_dic`, [plus some convenient methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects).

For instance, if I want to print the 10 most frequent sequences, together with their counts:

```
print(*seq_counter.most_common(10), sep="\n")
```